# ADC value changing after changing Timer1 value in program

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, analogread, adc

I'm writing a code where `analogRead()` reads ADC value from load. After reading ADC value, if it is not in range, I need to manipulate Timer1 value. Which is also getting changed.
But, after changing the Timer value,  if the load value again gets restored, ADC doesn't show the same value again, but shows some other value.

Please refer below code:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

int LED = 13;
int IN0 = 12;
int IN1 = 11;
int OUT1 = 10;
int OUT2 = 9;
int OUT3 = 8;
int OUT4 = 7;
//float A0;
//int OUT5 = 6;
const float refvolt = 5.0;
int volts = 0;
byte tempL_flag = 0;
float samples, loadval, avgacs, acsvaluef =0;
float refval = 2.0;
bool lflag=0;
unsigned long count = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(IN0, INPUT);
    pinMode(IN1, INPUT);
    pinMode(OUT1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(OUT2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(OUT3, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(OUT4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(A0, INPUT);
    //digitalWrite(OUT3, LOW);
    Timer1.initialize(370000);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

word ADC_READ(byte sample, byte tim, byte CH)
{
    word adcdata;
    word avrdata;
    word abcdata;
    byte i;

    for(i=0; i<sample; i++)
    {
        adcdata = 0;
        adcdata = analogRead(CH);
        avrdata = avrdata + adcdata;
        delay(tim);
    }
    return(avrdata/sample);
}

void flash_L()
{
    digitalWrite(LED, !digitalRead(LED));
    digitalWrite(OUT4, !digitalRead(OUT4));

    if (digitalRead(OUT4)==1)
    {
        loadval = ADC_READ(10, 10, A5);
        Serial.println(loadval);

        if(loadval < refval)
        {
            Timer1.initialize(185000);
        }
        else
        {
            tempL_flag = 1;
        }
        return;
    }
}

void loop() {

    delay(2000);

    if(digitalRead(IN0)==1)
    {
        Timer1.attachInterrupt(flash_L);
    }
    else if(digitalRead(IN0)==0)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        digitalWrite(OUT4, LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: how many times do you want to attach the same interrupt? It starts counitng again at attach. Put attachInterrupt in setup(). And I wouldn't read ADC in interrupt.

Comment: Only when input is read, Interrupt is generated. Yes there is ADC in interrupt , I've written a function for sampling. `loadval = ADC_READ(10, 10, A5);`

Comment: I don't see why would be IN0 HIGH only one loop of the loop(). And you never detach the interrupt or set it back to 370000

Comment: Let me explain. If high gets to IN0, Timer will be at 370000. Timer Interrupt will occur.  It will read ADC on load. If load is in range 370000 will continue. If not,  185000. But after load is out of range and Timer is at 185000, if load is restored, timer should be back at 370000. But even if load is restored, ADC value changes and is not same as in previous case, So I cannot jump back to 370000. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: "If high gets to IN0, Timer will be at 370000." how? "Timer Interrupt will occur" and will do what? the function is not attached to interrupt yet.

Comment: @Juraj sir, if you refer code, in setup() timer has been initialized to 370000. IN0 will be high by external switch. You can see in loop(), if IN0 is high, interrupt is attached flash_L is ISR. In ISR LED and Bulb are toggeled. If this doesn't answer your qstn. I think I'm not getting your qstn

Comment: IN0 is HIGH, the interrupt gets attached. at next 370000 micros multiple it fires  and from then it fires always again at next 370000 or 185000 microseconds

Comment: @Juraj I think I'm unable to understand what you are saying. I'm not getting your question. 370000 will only change to 185000 if load is not in range. If load is back in range after distortion, I'm not getting the same value of ADC that showed before it distorted.

Comment: do you understand that the set timer value of TimerOne is a period at which the attached function will be called repeatedly? so you want to attach the interrupt in setup() or detach it in interrupt. do you want it run repeatedly or as one shot?

Comment: @Juraj yes i do understand. That means after 370000 microseconds interuupt will be called and I need to write ISR for that. You can see in setup(), I've initialized the timer. in loop the interrupt (flash_L) has been called. after IN0 is high. yes I want to run it repeatedly every time the IN0 is high.

Comment: it will run always after next period, once attached. and it will not run 300000 after you attached it. it will run 300000 micros after you initialized the period. so the logic of your sketch doesn't make sense, because you don't understand how TimerOne library works

Comment: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimerOne.html

Comment: OP keeps talking about it getting set back to 370000 but I don't see anywhere in the code where that happens.  Once it gets set to 185000 it will always stay there no matter the load.

Comment: @Delta_G yes in code its nowhere getting back to 185000 bcz once load is restored, ADC value not getting back. So I haven't written that part of code. My main aim is to get ADC value restored then need to change timer value

Comment: @Juraj Okay thanks for your help. But doing this timer thing right will give correct ADC values? Help me in that if timer and ADC are linked likewise

Comment: @Juraj I tried your suggestion, and studies the link you shared. Then initialized timer after IN0 high and YES!! its done. Thank you soo much. :)

Answer (score 1):

> ADC doesn't show the same value again

You are not reading the ADC correctly, so `ADC_READ()` can return
anything. See the comments in the code:

```cpp
word ADC_READ(byte sample, byte tim, byte CH)
{
    word adcdata;  // not needed
    word avrdata;  // not initialized
    word abcdata;  // not used
    byte i;
    for (i = 0; i < sample; i++)
    {
        adcdata = 0;  // useless
        adcdata = analogRead(CH);
        avrdata = avrdata + adcdata;
        delay(tim);
    }
    return (avrdata/sample);
}
```

The big issue is `avrdata` not being initialized. Its initial value is
whatever was left there (in the stack or some CPU registers) by the code
that ran before. The value returned by the function is then hard to
predict and depends on what the rest of the program is doing.

The other remarks I left in the comments are not that problematic,
although they are revealing of some lack of attention to detail. Same
for some badly named variables. Here is how I would implement this
function:

```cpp
word ADC_READ(byte samples, byte time, byte channel)
{
    word sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
    {
        sum += analogRead(channel);
        delay(time);
    }
    return sum/samples;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I will try you suggestion. thank you

Comment: its not working sir, I tried your code. I think its having problem with timer and ADC function jumping back to 370000 from 185000

Comment: @HrishikeshDixit: I am not addressing the timer issue. I am just showing you how to correctly average ADC readings, which the program you posted doesn't do.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the suggestion, it did save variable and some lines of code. Thank you!